# Adding Basic Auth to Kafka Connect

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My Kafka cluster is managed by Heroku and is secured via SSL. I can successfully authenticate between the Kafka Connect client and Kafka broker, and I can deploy connectors that also communicate via SSL.

ELI5: How do I just add username/password or token auth to *Connect's REST API*??

##### Problem

1. My `KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL` is still set to `SSL`. Does this need to change? Im **not enabling** SASL on the *broker*, **only the API**
2. My Dockerfile uses `appuser`.. is this correct?

I am trying to add Basic Auth to the Kafka Connect REST API (ex: `/connectors`). I've followed the steps:

1. Add basic auth extension: `CONNECT_REST_EXTENSION_CLASSES="org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.BasicAuthSecurityRestExtension"`
2. Create `connect_jaas.conf`:

```
KafkaConnect {
 org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.PropertyFileLoginModule required
 file="/app/rest-credentials.properties
}
```

3. Create `rest-credentials.properties` : `appuser=testpassword`
4. Add path to jaas.conf: `KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/app"`

##### Debugging:

Output from `heroku run bash`

```
bash-4.4$ cat rest-credentials.properties 
testuser=<redacted password>
bash-4.4$ cat connect_jaas.conf 
KafkaConnect {
org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.PropertyFileLoginModule required
  file="/app/rest-credentials.properties"
}
bash-4.4$ echo $KAFKA_OPTS
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/app/connect_jaas.conf
bash-4.4$ echo $CONNECT_REST_EXTENSION_CLASSES
org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.BasicAuthSecurityRestExtension
```

Comment: 1) You're missing a quote on the `file=` 2) `java.security.auth.login.config` needs to point to the JAAS file, not a directory. Ref https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/basic-auth.html#basic-auth-kconnect

Comment: @OneCricketeer - That was just a typo, I copied the values from config vars. All the syntax is correct - does basic auth affect things like `security.protocol`? Also - the error I get is `user cannot access resource`

Comment: The Kafka SSL connection (security protocol) isn't related. That is the expected response if you pass the wrong user... Does this help? https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker#http-authentication

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for sharing that (and for being so active on the Kafka support here, many more than I appreciate it). I noticed I was missing a `;` in `file="/app/rest-credentials.properties";` as well...

I see you specify `admin: OneCricketeer` in `credentials.properties`... could this error be the result of not specifying a role for `testuser=testpassword`?

Comment: It's not a "role". The file format is `username:  password`. See the link in the first comment. Colons are used, not equal signs

Comment: However... `Properties.load` should accept `key=value` formatted files too, so maybe that's not the problem https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/basic-auth-extension/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/rest/basic/auth/extension/PropertyFileLoginModule.java#L73

Comment: @OneCricketeer Do you have an example repo by chance? If I comment out `KAFKA_OPTS`, `CONNECT_REST_EXTENSION_CLASSES`, AND `KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS` the API works fine - but as soon as I add those in (which reference the `.conf` & `.properties` files, I get "connection refused"

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Additionally - I do see `:ro` [appended to your volumes](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker#http-authentication) - does this have any use?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I figured it out... **confluent** expects a `.jaas` and a `.password` file instead of a `.properties` file.. there was a `/etc/kafka/connect.password` with sample data. Once I overwrote `connect.password` in `/etc/kafka/connect.password` and referenced that file, Im able to access with basic auth

Comment: "Confluent" doesn't expect anything. I linked you to the source code of that JAAS module, from _Apache Kafka_ which is all that you're using here. It reads whatever `file` option that is configured. Then, the JVM property doesn't validate file extensions either... My `:ro` is a habit since I dont want the container to try to modify the files. Glad you figured it out, though. Feel free to provide your working solution below.